# Want to convert 14.8v to 5v at Max 30 Amp current draw

Tags: current, resistors, voltage-regulator, resistance, voltage-divider

I want to convert 14.8v to 5v at Max 30 Amp current draw. IS this possible using resistors?? I don't know that how much current a resistors can draw without any circuit issue. [Readymate solution for very small current.](https://robu.in/product/xl4015-5a-dc-dc-step-adjustable-power-supply-buck-module-led-w-heatsink/)

Comment: If you want to always have 5 V for any current up to 30 A, then no, that's not possible using resistors only. You have to specify what delivers the 14.8 V and what uses the 5 V because possible solutions can vary and can depend on those devices.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have a lithium-ion battery that can deliver 14.8 v and max 30 Amp current. I want to step down 14.8v to 5v. I have 7-8 sensor which needs 5v input and they draw different-different current like one need 2A and other need 0.15A. So, which type of circuit should i make to step down 14.8v to 5v and one more thing i need 30 Amp battery because my motor can draw maximum 7Amp current at 14V.

Comment: Now edit your question and add that ^^ information to it.

Comment: https://robu.in/product/lm2596-dc-dc-buck-converter-step-down-module-power-supply-output-1-23v-30v/?gclid=CjwKCAjwtO7qBRBQEiwAl5WC2125zek64KbHLM_xKEsiexlu3cnCu0_jSORmGP4ZbXTDf4NmqSms-RoC6owQAvD_BwE

Comment: https://robu.in/product/xl4015-5a-dc-dc-step-adjustable-power-supply-buck-module-led-w-heatsink/

Comment: I hope it didn't take you more than one year to find that link. Now use **edit** to edit your question and include the link there, in the question. And where does it say that this generic LM2596 buck converter module supports 30 A?

Comment: I just add that for others if they need this.

Comment: Sure I'll do that.

Comment: O_O still stuck on this for one year ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you lack knowledge (apologies if I am wrong) to attempt any serious circuit by yourself. In that case your best bet would be so called BEC device available from any hobby store. Something like [this one](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/yep-20a-hv-2-12s-sbec-w-selectable-voltage-output.html).

Comment: But if I want to make this type of circuit then can you please help me a little bit?

Comment: The BEC that I linked to is switch mode power supply, and quite powerful for its size I must add. I can't help you with that, other than suggest doing a research on SMPS and post specific questions on that one if you have them.

Comment: Thank you for the information.